# How make a drop-down list in a telegram chat bot with aiogram3

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, chatbot, aiogram

I'm trying to create a drop-down list to select a country. Because the list is very large, I can't use inline keyboard. For this I would like to use a drop-down list like in desktop, mobile, web, etc. apps.

Answer (score 0):

Since the possibility of implementing a drop-down list could not be found even in the [official telegram documentation](https://core.telegram.org/api), it was decided to ask the user to enter the name of the country manually, then using [thefuzz](https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz) fuzzy text comparison library to check all the countries from the list. Show the country with the highest score to the user for clarification (with a flag and label in the native language).

```py
from rapidfuzz import fuzz


def comparison(target: str, texts: list[str]) -> None | str:
    candidate: dict = {"score": 0, "name": ""}
    pre_candidate: dict = {"score": 0, "name": ""}

    for text in texts:
        score = fuzz.ratio(target, text)

        if score > candidate["score"]:
            candidate = {"score": score, "name": text}
        elif score == candidate["score"]:
            pre_candidate = {"score": score, "name": text}

    if candidate["score"] == pre_candidate["score"]:
        return None

    return candidate["name"]
```